# Solving multiple inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions, inequalities, subscript

I am new to Mathematica and I want to know if there are solutions to the following 4 coupled inequalities.

Note that the inequalities are long and cumbersome with many variables with subscripts (I guess the size of the inequalities shouldn't matter for Mathematica, though!). However,
when I run the cell, nothing seems to happen. Is there a problem with my code?

```
(* Note that C2 = Cb, C1 = Cq, Subscript[κ, 2] = Subscript[κ, b] and 
  Subscript[κ, 1]= Subscript[κ, q ]*)

$Assumptions = 
 n > 0 && Subscript[κ, 1] > 0 && Subscript[κ, 2] > 0 && 
  Subscript[C, 1] > 0 && Subscript[C, 2] > 0 ;

inequality1 = 
 Subscript[θ, 9]  <= Subscript[κ, 1]/(4 n^2) ;
inequality2 = 
 3 Subscript[βθ, 8]
     n + (3/2) (Subscript[ηθ, 5]) Subscript[C, 1] n^3 - 
   8 Subscript[βκ, 2] - Subscript[ηκ, 
   1] + β (Subscript[ν, 3]^(-1) + 
      4 Subscript[ν, 4]^(-1) + Subscript[θ, 6]^(-1) + 
      4 Subscript[θ, 7]^(-1) + 
      6 Subscript[θ, 8]^(-1) + 
      4 Subscript[θ, 9]^(-1)) <= 0;
inequality3 = 
 n^3 (3 Subscript[βν, 5] Subscript[C, 2] + 
      Subscript[γθ, 2] Subscript[C, 
       1] + (3/2) Subscript[ηθ, 4] Subscript[C, 1] n + 
      2 Subscript[βθ, 7] Subscript[C, 1] n^2)
   - 6 Subscript[ηκ, 2] - Subscript[γκ, 1]
   + η (Subscript[ν, 1]^(-1) + 3 Subscript[ν, 2]^(-1) + 
      Subscript[θ, 3]^(-1) + 3 Subscript[θ, 4]^(-1) + 
      3 Subscript[θ, 5]^(-1)) <= 0;
inequality4 = 
 n^3 (3 Subscript[ην, 2] Subscript[C, 2] + 
      4 Subscript[βν, 5] Subscript[C, 2]
        n + (1/2) Subscript[θ, 0] Subscript[C, 
       1] + (1/2) Subscript[γθ, 1] Subscript[C, 1]
        n + (1/2) Subscript[ηθ, 3] n^3 Subscript[C, 
       1] + (1/2) Subscript[βθ, 6] n^3 Subscript[C, 
       1]) - γ (4 Subscript[κ, 2] + Subscript[κ,
       1]) + γ (Subscript[ν, 0]^(-1) + 
      Subscript[θ, 1]^(-1) + Subscript[θ, 2]^(-1)) <= 
  0; 
inequality5 = 
 n^3 (Subscript[γν, 0] Subscript[C, 2] + 
      Subscript[ην, 1] Subscript[C, 2] n + 
      Subscript[βν, 3] Subscript[C, 2] n^5) + 
   Subscript[θ, 0]^(-1) - Subscript[κ, 2] <= 0 ;

(*Use Solve to find a solution *)
solution = 
FindInstance[{inequality1, inequality2, inequality3, inequality4, 
  inequality5}, {γ, β, η, Subscript[ν, 0], 
  Subscript[ν, 1], Subscript[ν, 2], Subscript[ν, 3], 
  Subscript[ν, 4], Subscript[ν, 5], Subscript[θ, 0], 
  Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[θ, 2], Subscript[θ,
   3], Subscript[θ, 4], Subscript[θ, 5], 
  Subscript[θ, 6], Subscript[θ, 6], Subscript[θ,
   7], Subscript[θ, 8], Subscript[θ, 9]}, PositiveReals]

(*Check if a solution exists*)
If[solution === {}, Print["No solution found."], 
Print["Solution(s):", solution]]
```

Comment: Or MAYBE you aren't really looking for a numeric solution to your problem and you are looking for a more symbolic solution containing all those variables that you didn't include. If that is the case then perhaps `Reduce` might be a better choice. If you could better explain what kind of solution you are looking for then that might help a lot.

Comment: @Bill Yes I am looking for a symbolic solution. why should I include ην2 since it is not a single variable. My variables are γ,β,η,ν0,ν1,ν2,ν3,ν4,ν5,θ0,θ1,θ2,θ3,θ4,θ5,θ6,θ6,θ7,θ8,θ9,C1,C2,n

Comment: `FindInstance` only finds numeric results. `Reduce` can can find symbolic. Please edit your question to describe exactly the solution you need. Maybe that will get someone to offer an even better solution. `Reduce` with 5 inequalities and 5 variables rapidly finishes. With more variables it may take longer or even not finish. Pick 5 vars and look at the `InputForm` of the solution from `Reduce` so you can see all the details, but `InputForm` is only for looking at the result and can't be used in further calculations. May be too many alt solutions. Sorry I missed a space between 2 characters.

Comment: If you get too many alternate solutions with lots of nested `&&` and `||` it may be difficult to understand. `LogicalExpand` can expand that into "here is one complete solution" OR "here is a second complete solution" OR "here is a third complete solution" OR ... Be careful if you try to do further calculations with that result.